# Is it possible to inject an object with scala-guice?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice

I would like to inject the `scala.io.Source` but I failed to find a working solution. This is what I have so far:

```
class Foo @Inject()(var source:Source) {
  // ...
}
```

And the binding:

```
class DependencyInjection extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  def configure:Unit = {
     bind[Source.type].to[Source]
     // bind[Source] didn't work
  }
}
```

Maybe I can wrap the `scala.io.Source` calls into a local `class` but it doesn't sound right. Is there a way to inject objects with scala-guice?

Comment: I have never worked with `ScalaModule`, but irrespective of it how can you bind `Source` with itself?

Comment: By definition `Source.type` is inhabited only by `Source`. This makes its injection pointless - the only thing that can be injected can be `Source` itself, and you can as well just use it directly.

Comment: BTW, please clarify: do you want to inject `Source` companion object (of type `Source.type`) or you want to inject some instance of `Source` class (of type `Source`)? These are very different things, and injection `Source` companion object is pointless, as I said.

Comment: @Jatin I tried everything - no bind, bind to itself, bind to .type and nothing worked.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev the Source.type was just a trial because nothing else worked and I saw in other question that this might work. And I think injection is not pointless because in my class I would like to have control over the Source so that it won't do anything on the filesystem during test.

Comment: @Zsolt, I meant that injection objects of type `Source.type` is pointless because there is only one of them exists, namely `Source` companion object. But now I do see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Source` is an abstract class, and there are no public extensions for it (and even if there were, you wouldn't be able to use them anyway since they likely wouldn't have been Guice-enabled), you'll have to use providers or `@Provide` methods.

Providers:

```
class Config extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  override def configure: Unit = {
    bind[Source].toProvider(new Provider[Source] {
      override def get = Source.fromFile("whatever.txt")(Codec.UTF8)
    })
  }
}

// you can also extract provider class and use `toProviderType[]` extension 
// from scala-guice:

class FromFileSourceProvider extends Provider[Source]
  override def get = Source.fromFile("whatever.txt")(Codec.UTF8)
}

class Config extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  override def configure: Unit = {
    bind[Source].toProviderType[FromFileSourceProvider]
  }
}
```

Another way is to use `@Provides` methods:

```
class Config extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  @Provides def customSource: Source = Source.fromFile("whatever.txt")(Codec.UTF8)
  // that's it, nothing more
}
```

I'd also suggest adding a binding annotation to distinguish between different sources in your program, though it entirely depends on your architecture.

This approach is no different from that in Java, when you need to inject classes which are not Guice-enabled or available through factory methods only.