# How does @Inject in Scala work

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I'm wondering how does @Inject annotation in Play-Scala works. It obviously injects a dependency, but I'm curious how is it working. When I was using it on class extending controller and set routes generator to injectroutesgenerator it seems to autmagically create objects from those classes, but how do I use it in other context?

I tried:

```
@Inject val mailer: MailerClient = null
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Are there any posibilities to @Inject things (that mailerClient, WS ets.) directly to a value, not to controller class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks close.  Change `val` to `var` because it is not final and needs to be injected at a latter stage.

```
@Inject var mailer: MailerClient = null
```

I'd check also that the `MailerClient` library is mentioned as a dependency in the project configuration.  You could try with `WSClient` instead as it's included by default in the template:

```
@Inject var ws: WSClient = null
```

Especially as I know that this particular one works.

#### Update

Created a [demo on GitHub](https://github.com/bjfletcher/play-inject-field-example) which is the `Play-Scala` template with the `index` method changed as follows:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

class Application extends Controller {

  @Inject var ws: WSClient = null

  def index = Action.async {
    ws.url("http://google.com").get.map(r => Ok(r.body))
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems legit but still nullPointerException

Comment: When inject MailerClient into class it work as dream, but when i do it like that: "@Inject var mailer: MailerClient = null"

https://github.com/Hajtosek/mailTest/blob/master/app/service/Mail.scala

Comment: So you're telling me that i can ONLY use @Inject on Controllers?

Comment: You can use it in classes or traits, not objects but you can use the @Singleton annotation for a similar behaviour - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html

Comment: So, this should theoretically work?      https://github.com/Hajtosek/mailTest/blob/master/app/service/Mail.scala

Comment: That's fine, you'll need to tell the system about the injectable module (@Singleton by itself isn't enough). Have a look at this for a Play 2.4 specific example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30959808/722180 Have a look also at this for more Scala ways of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24823300/722180