# How to do database initialization when using DI in Play 2.4?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.4

Play 2.4 discourages using [`GlobalSettings.onStart` and whole `Global` object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings).

I'm using play-slick and it has [great DI sample in GitHub](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/di), but it is missing a example how to do database initialization.

How does one implement the database initialization when using DI and when GlobalSettings.onStart is not available?

Common cases for database initialization is: If in DEV mode, add these rows, if PROD do these. Examples wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to place the initialisation in the *constructor* of the injected class.  Here's an example:

Add `app/modules/Database.scala`:

```
package modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import com.google.inject.name.Names

trait Database {
  def create(): Unit
  def drop(): Unit
}

class TestDatabase extends Database {
  initialize() // running initialization in constructor
  def initialize() = {
    println("Setup database with test data here")
  }
  def create() = ()
  def drop() = ()
}

class ProdDatabase extends Database {
  // similar to above
}

class DatabaseModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[Database])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("development"))
      .to(classOf[TestDatabase]).asEagerSingleton
    bind(classOf[Database])
      .annotatedWith(Names.named("production"))
      .to(classOf[TestDatabase])
  }
}
```

Add in `conf/application.conf`:

```
play.modules.enabled += "DatabaseModule"
```

That's to start with. The `.asEagerSingleton` will run the constructor code without needing you to inject it. When you want to choose which one to inject, then you'd need to remove the `.asEagerSingleton` and load the appropriate database implementation either:

- based on [configuration in the bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings#Configurable-bindings) (see link for example); or
- in the service/controller, for example:

  @Inject @Named("development") Database database