# What's the point of dependency injection if you still have to pass in an argument?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, slick

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the basic idea of dependency injection. (I'm using Play 2.5 with the play-slick module) Say I have a class `Users` that needs a database connection.

```
package models

@Singleton
class Users @Inject() (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {

  private val db = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile].db

  private val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

  private val setupAction = DBIO.seq(users.schema.create)

  private val setupFuture: Future[Unit] = db.run(setupAction)

  def getAll(): Future[Seq[User]] = setupFuture.flatMap(_ =>
    db.run(users.result)
  )

  // More methods like the previous
}
```

When I have a view that needs to access these methods, I would expect the dependency injection system to fill out `dbConfigProvider` dependency for me, like this.

```
package views

class UserSearch {

  def index(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[String] = Future(
    (new Users).getAll().map(seq => seq.map(user => user.name).mkString(" "))
  )

}
```

However this gives me a compilation error and I am forced to make `dbConfigProvider` a dependency of my view and pass it in explicitly. In this case I finally get the `dbConfigProvider` from a controller calling the view.

```
package views

class UserSearch @Inject (dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {

  def index(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[String] = Future(
    (new Users(dbConfigProvider)).getAll().map(seq =>
      seq.map(user => user.name).mkString(" "))
  )

}
```

I'm assuming I've misunderstood how dependency injection should work.

So my questions are as follows:

1. What's the point of using the `@Inject()` keyword in my model `Users` then?
2. Is my design patter flawed? I would love to have `Users` and `UserSearch` be objects, but then I can't use dependency injection on them.
3. In case anyone is familiar with Slick, is my `getAll()` method the propper way to be working with slick? Is this even the correct way to write asynchronous code?

Comment: `UserSearch` should inject `Users`, not the `DatabaseConfigProvider` that `Users` needs. There is no reason `UserSearch` needs to know about that.

Comment: @MichaelZajac Thanks, but then would I create the instance of `new Users` in my controller's Action method every time?

Comment: No, the DI framework is supposed to create all of the dependencies for you. If you need to use `Users` in your controller, it should be injected into your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MichaelZajac comments, I changed `UserSearch` to be declared as so:

```
class UserSearch @Inject (users: Users)
```

And I now have my controller set up like this:

```
class UsersController @Inject()(userSearch: UserSearch) extends Controller {

  def index = Action.async {
    implicit request => userSearch.index().map(Ok(_))
  }

}
```

This answers my first question directly, and seeing this in action also answers my second question. I'm now getting SQL errors, but at least my project compiles. I later figured out my third question – turns out that there is no reason to create the table scheme, because in my case it is done by play evolutions files, thus I removed the `setupFuture.flatMap` part, even though it works fine with it, and doesn't do anything stupid like creating the table twice, or whatever else you might need to do on table creation/start-up.

Answer (score 0):

one of the advantages of DI, is the easiness to use other implementations, specially useful in tests where you can pass a mock on the arguments.

For instance, if you receive an instance of a class (`MyExternalClass`) that will invoke external APIs, you can instead send a subclass (`MyExternalSubClass extends MyExternalClass`) that would override the method that calls the API, and simply return a preconfigured json

There are also several advantages (and disadvantages) listed here (many other interesting articles on the web):

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-containers
- https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-when-we-are-implementing-the-dependency-injection

Comment: Why wouldn't that work without dependency injection though?